# Code to Run Multiple Selenium Webdriver JUnit Class In a Batch File

Tags: selenium, batch-file, webdriver

I have multiple selenium test classes. They are independent of each other.

Can anyone please tell me the code to put in a batch file to run multiple test class by simply clicking on the batch file?

Consider my java test classes are located in my local folder: "C:\WebDriver Effort\inspection\src\test\java\com".

Comment: A good start would be to observe what you get if you type this at a command prompt.   "C:\WebDriver Effort\inspection\src\test\java\com" /?

Comment: It says "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: oops!  My comment above makes no sense!  What I was looking for was info about these "selenium test classes".  There is nothing to go on to provide any kind of answer to this question.  What do you execute to run these test classes?  Execute that followed by /? on a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Writing batch file is not big deal. First try to execute your testcases from command prompt.

If your test cases have main class you can execute like this.

```
cd C:\WebDriver_Effort\inspection\src\test\java\com\
javac Test1.java  //compile testcase
java Test1         //running testcase
```

Make sure that selenium.jar is in your classpath otherwise mention the that while compiling.

```
javac -cp "Selenium-standaloneserver.jar" Test1.java  //compile testcase
java -cp "Selenium-standaloneserver.jar" Test1         //running testcase
```

If you've written test cases in JUnit format follow the steps mentioned in this [link](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/03/running-junit-test-cases-from-cmd-prompt.html)